# A doubt on Proposition 5.1.12 of Liu's Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a scheme. Let $0 \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H} \to 0$ be an exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. If two of them are quasi-coherent, then so is the third.

This is the point $(d)$ of Proposition 5.1.12 of Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic curves. I need only to show the case in which $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are quasi-coherent. By local nature of quasi-coherent sheaves, we may assume that $X$ is affine. We know by Proposition 1.8 of the same book that the sequence

$0 \to \mathcal{F}(X) \to \mathcal{G}(X) \to \mathcal{H}(X) \to 0$

is exact. Now it is said that we have a commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    0 @>>> \mathcal{F}(X)' @>>> \mathcal{G}(X)' @>>> \mathcal{H}(X)' @>>>0\\
    & @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
    0 @>>>\mathcal{F} @>>> \mathcal{G} @>>> \mathcal{F} @>>>0
\end{CD}

With $\mathcal{F}(X)',\mathcal{G}(X)',\mathcal{H}(X)'$ i indicate the sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules induced by the modules $\mathcal{F}(X),\mathcal{G}(X),\mathcal{H}(X)$. The first and the last vertical arrow are the isomorphisms we have by hypothesis. I don't understand how is the vertical arrow in the middle of the diagram above defined and so i cannot understand why the diagram is commutative.

Comment: Does this give you what you want?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_five_lemma

Comment: Yes. It follows from that. But i need to know why the diagram Is commutative and so how Is defined the arrow in the middle to use the snake lemma.

Comment: The arrow in the middle is defined the same as the ones on the right and left, I think.  So your question comes down to why the diagram is commutative

Comment: The right and left ones do exist because i know by hypothesis that $\mathcal{F}(X)' \cong \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}(X)' \cong \mathcal{G}$. Why does exist an arrow $\mathcal{G}(X)' \to \mathcal{G}$?

Comment: Ah I see.  I'm typing an answer now.  When $X$ is affine, there is always a morphism of sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$ modules $\widetilde{\mathcal G(X)} \rightarrow \mathcal G$.  It is an isomorphism precisely when $\mathcal G$ is quasi-coherent.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = \operatorname{Spec}A$ be an affine scheme.  If $M$ is an $A$-module, there is an associated sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules $\widetilde{M}$ defined in the usual way by defining $\widetilde{M}(U)$ to be a certain $\mathcal O_X(U)$-submodule of

$$\prod\limits_{\mathfrak p \in X} M_{\mathfrak p}$$
Let $\mathcal F$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules, so that $\mathcal F(X)$ is an $\mathcal O_X(X) = A$-module.  Then $\widetilde{\mathcal F(X)}$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules as defined above.

There is an associated morphism of sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules $\theta = \theta_{\mathcal F}:\widetilde{\mathcal F(X)} \rightarrow \mathcal F$.  I think your question comes down to asking:

> 1 .  How is $\theta$ defined?
>
> 2 . Why is $\theta$ natural? (this will imply the commutativity of the diagram)  In other words, if $\alpha: \mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal G$ is a morphism of sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules, we should get another morphism $\widetilde{\alpha}: \widetilde{\mathcal F(X)} \rightarrow \widetilde{\mathcal G(X)}$ as in your diagram, and it should satisfy $\alpha \circ \theta_{\mathcal F} = \widetilde{\alpha} \circ \theta_{\mathcal G}$.

Comment: Yes, that is my question.

Comment: Let me try to explain. We are assuming that $X$ is affine. Let $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(X) $ and $D(f)$ a principal open subset. Then we have a map $\mathcal{F}(X)'(X)_f=\mathcal{F}(X) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X(X)} \mathcal{O}_X(D(f)) \to \mathcal{F}(D(f))$, which sends $s \otimes a \mapsto a \cdot \left. s \right\vert_{D(f)}$. Gluing all together we get a morphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathcal{F}(X)' \to \mathcal{F}$. This should be the morphism that always exists. The fact that the diagram is commutative easily follows; now that i know how the morphism in the middle is defined.